# screen support in kivy set to normal and large screens

Tags: android, python-2.7, kivy

Is there a way to establish a "supports-screens" kind of configuration to make my application available only for normal and large screens android devices.is there a way to do this with the build.py script?(i have bets on --intent-filters option but not sure how it might be used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it from the build.py. However, you can change manually the `templates/AndroidManifest.xml.tmpl` and adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Hey @tito! nice job with Kivy, it is an excellent platform; Respect! As for my issue i have solved it without changing the manifest, i have used in the kv file percentages for the width and height of my widgets and now it is working on small and large screens i have also published my app recently, here it is : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=l.l.l.l it is called "Lebanese Payroll Calculator", thank you for replying and wish you the best of luck with the Kivy project.

Comment: If you can do it with kv, that's a better way yes :) Also for your app, maybe you want to use https://plyer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#plyer.facades.Email

Comment: that is great! i'll check the docs! sounds interesting! Thank you!

Comment: i have been reading the link that you have provided, but i could not find how to install the plyer module on my linux in order to test it. Can you please assist? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/kivy/plyer < this is where the source code live. Careful, not everything is available on all platforms. When you use python-for-android, it's already included.

Comment: Ok great i'll check it.merci beaucoup! Très gentil de ta part;)